# unpacking data without removing trailing null bytes or spaces

Tags: php, pack, unpack

If you do `extract(unpack('a*demo', "a\0\0\0")); echo strlen($demo);` you won't get 4 back - you'll get 1 back. This is because the `a`, per http://php.net/pack, is a "NUL-padded string" so the trailing NUL bytes are being removed.

My question is...  is there a way to make it so that they're not removed?

I could do `A*demo` instead of `a*demo` and then null bytes wouldn't be removed but trailing spaces would be.

Comment: Why are you unpacking a string if you want the whole string?

Comment: Well, golly, if all I'm doing is outputting `4` why didn't I just do `echo 4;`? Durr. Seriously, it's just a contrived snippet of code demonstrating the problem I'm having. If it feels too contrived than pretend I posted `extract(unpack('avar/a*demo', "aa\0\0\0")); echo strlen($demo);` instead. Now I'm not getting the whole string anymore. Better?

Comment: Can you determine where the substring of interest starts and ends?

Comment: Yes. I can do multiple substrings to map a particular file to the various variables but rather than do 100 substrings I'd rather do 1x `unpack`. And, sure, I can do `str_pad` to add the null bytes that `unpack` is removing but it'd be nice if I didn't have to do that.. I'm looking into `sscanf` as an alternative as well but am running into issues with that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33459217/569976